# Project view / file navigation while in presentation mode

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to show the project tab (left side file navigation) while being in presentation mode?

I know I can switch files with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, but I would like to show the whole file structure to my audience.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The same keyboard shortcuts work in the **presentation mode**, so <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (Mac <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) will show the Project View. You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> (hold) (Mac <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>) shortcut to temporarily display tool window buttons and activate any tool window with a mouse.

- [Manipulating the Tool Windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html)
- [Want more effective IntelliJ IDEA screen estate?](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/07/want-more-effective-intellij-idea-screen-estate/)

Answer (score 0):

As a shortcut you can use `Ctrl+Tab` to switch between files.